# NSIS SelectFileDialog filter not being applied

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I have used the following line in an NSIS script:

***nsDialogs::SelectFileDialog* open "C:\temp.rar" "*.rar"**

When I run the resultant installer (in Windows 10) the file dialog opens to C: as it should, *temp.rar* shows in the File name field, and *.*rar* shows in the filter dropdown. However **the filter is not being applied to the file list**. That is, all filetypes are still visible, despite *.*rar* being the only entry in the filter dropdown.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is unfortunately not clear on this but it uses the same format as the `GetOpenFileName` function in Windows; the filter is a list of pairs; display string and DOS filter:

```
nsDialogs::SelectFileDialog open "C:\temp.rar" "*.rar|*.rar"
Pop $0
nsDialogs::SelectFileDialog open "C:\temp.rar" ".rar files|*.rar|All Files|*.*"
Pop $0
```

Keep in mind that the filter is only there to help the user but the user can type in any file name they want even if it does not match the active filter.

Comment: I will try to fix the documentation.

Comment: This worked great, thank you. I wasn't realizing that a pair is required. Once I changed "\*.rar" to "\*.rar|*.rar" it worked perfectly. This helped me to realize that I could use "Archives (.rar)|*.rar" to make it even prettier.